# trying to get timespent by the user for quiz

Tags: javascript, html

```
 <input class="btnAction" onclick="countdown(time)" type="submit" name="finish" id="finish"  style="display:none;"> 
//trying to get the time when user submits quiz
function countdown(minutes) {
    var seconds = 60;
    var mins = minutes
    var time = document.getElementById("timer").innerText;
    function tick() {
        var counter = document.getElementById("timer");
        var current_minutes = mins-1
        seconds--;


                  //return time;
                  //alert(time);
        counter.innerHTML = current_minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
        if( seconds > 0 ) { 
            setTimeout(tick, 1000);

        } else {

            if(mins > 1){  

               // countdown(mins-1);   never reach “00″ issue solved:Contributed by Victor Streithors
               setTimeout(function () { countdown(mins - 1); }, 1000);

            }
             else 
              {
                    alert("your time has been ended");
                  document.getElementById('test-form').submit();
                 // var time = document.getElementById("timer").innerText.split(":").map(function(val){ return parseInt(val)});
                 //        console.log("minutes",time[0]);
                 //        console.log("seconds",time[1]);

              }
        }
    }
    tick();
}

countdown(2);
```

for example if the user ends by 1 minute,i want to get the time spent for the quiz that is remaining 1 minute i would like to have this. can anyone help me please, starving to get time

Comment: You should post what you tried in javascript to get the time and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Below you can find an sample of how to start a quiz countdown.

```js
      var seconds = 300;
      function secondPassed() {
          var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60),
              remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;

          if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
              remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
          }

          document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
          if (seconds == 0) {
              clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        //your code here 
          } else {
              seconds--;
          }
      }
      var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
```

```css
.timer {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="timer">
            <time id="countdown">5:00</time>
</div>
```

how to get time

```
var time = document.getElementById("countdown").innerText.split(":").map(function(val){ return parseInt(val)});
console.log("minutes",time[0]);
console.log("seconds",time[1]);
```

Comment: i need to get the total time spent by the user

Comment: please provide more details , or a fiddle with your code

Comment: the code which you posted, is same as mine, you  have assigned <time id="countdown">5:00</time> here total time is 5.00, i need to get the time if user ends by 3.00

Comment: document.getElementById("countdown").innerText

Comment: how can i get the time onsubmit or onclick

Comment: add an event listener  on the submit button where you have to get the time and submit the quiz form